# Keycloak redirects me to my index url instead of to the requested one

Tags: spring-security, keycloak

I'm using Keycloak server (v 1.5.1) to perform an open-id-connect like authentication to my service. I've set up a basic web application which has two urls, the */index.html* one and other one called */hello*. I use Spring security, Spring boot and Spring MVC for all of that. That's my *pom.xml* configuration:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.keycloaktes</groupId>
    <artifactId>keycloaktes</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-spring-security-adapter</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-tomcat8-adapter</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

The issue comes when I address to */hello* url when not logged in, the keycloak login screen shows properly, but instead of performing a redirection to */hello* after successful login, it does it to my */index.html* page. That's how I've configured the security adapter:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = KeycloakSecurityComponents.class)
public class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    /**
     * Defines the session authentication strategy.
     */
    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(
                new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean keycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilterRegistrationBean(
            KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(
                filter);
        registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        return registrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean keycloakPreAuthActionsFilterRegistrationBean(
            KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(
                filter);
        registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        return registrationBean;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/*").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().permitAll();
        http.csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

I've been trying enabling both the `KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter` and `KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter`, but result keeps the same. Does anybody know how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to permit access to the SSO login entrypoint.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    super.configure(http);
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/sso/login*").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/*").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().permitAll();
    http.csrf().disable();
}
```

Spring Security roles are evaluated in the order they're declared so permitting access to `/sso/login` must come before more restrictive rules.